# PHP: var_dump while loop

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I was trying to create a loop for all the variables on a page to display in one while loop. I couldn't seem to get the variable to output. Here is the code I tried that made the most sense to me:

```
<?php
$varone = true;
$vartwo = 47;
$varthree = "A little string";

$vars = get_define_vars();

while($loop = $vars){
echo "variable ".$vars;
var_dump($vars;)
}
?>
```

It would crash one browser and the other it would stay blank. The reason I tried the code this way is because I thought of how I would word a mysql loop and I thought it would work in a similar way. Sorry if this is a newb question.

Comment: Tried to update to have a question.

Comment: Blank page is parse error `var_dump($vars;)` <<<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like a `foreach()` loop...

```
foreach ($vars  as $name => $var){
   echo "variable ".$name."=";
   var_dump($var);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I tried the code this way is because I thought of how I
>   would word a mysql loop and I thought it would work in a similar way.

Though I would go with `foreach` you can use your current code with `list` and `each` as many use to fetch from MySQL:

```
while(list($key, $val) = each($vars)){
    echo "variable $key";
    var_dump($val); //var_dump($vars;) PARSE ERROR check ;
}
```

However `each` is deprecated:

> **Warning** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on
>   this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I think it might be easier to use an array for this.

```
$new_array[] = true;
$new_array[] = 47;
$new_array[] = "A little string";

$a=0;
while($new_array[$a]){
    echo "variable ".$a." = ";
    var_dump($new_array[$a]);
    $a++;
}
```

Comment: Yes meanwhile that is true that using an array would work and be easier, I have them on a page that has different variables for different things.